# Is there a method that I can use to manage the spaces of the String in Java?

Tags: java

I am creating a program that displays information
Sample code :

```
String name="Name: ";
String age="Age: ";
String inputName=scanner.nextLine();
String inputAge=scanner.nextLine();
```

I want to display the output as

```
Name:    Jay
Age:     29
```

I tried to use if and else statements to get the same output but it is taking too much time and needs a lot of codes, I wonder if there is an easier way to do this. What is your way of writing code like this one?

Comment: if and else?  `System.out.println(name + "\t" + inputName); System.out.println(age + "\t" + inputAge);`

Comment: Thanks it works as hahaha.  I just made my previous code complex :)

Comment: here I was wondering why if-else is mentioned, thought I might have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```java
System.out.println(name + "\t" + inputName);
System.out.println(age+ "\t" + inputAge);
```

or you can try using the Print format function

```java
System.out.printf("name%15s", "inputName")
System.out.printf("age%15s", "inputAge")
```

or even

```java
System.out.printf("%-15sinputName", "name")
System.out.printf("%-15sinputAge", "age")
```